# Oracle connection problem with Toad

Tags: oracle10g, ora-01045

I created a new user - CK - with Toad on 10g XE. An error popup when I use CK to login: **ORA-01045: user CK lack create session privilege**. What privilege do I should give to CK?

BTW: but I can use SqlPlus to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant CREATE SESSION to the user you are trying to login as:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION ON [object] TO [user];
```

The CREATE SESSION privilege is granted to users in order to create a session to the database.  Without a session, you can't connect the database.  If you're curious, you could read this [Ask Tom: When not to use CREATE SESSION"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:178078700346681923)...

Here's a [good read on granting/revoking privileges](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php).

Comment: `grant create session to user` should be sufficiant.